# select blocks fifo from reading

Tags: c, linux, fifo

I have a problem with read() blocking mine program while trying to read from fifo. I want my program to read from multiple file descriptors and while one has information in it, it will write it on standard output.

I tried to use select but it seems not to work.

main.c (there is n number of the second program)

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    fd[i] = open(myfifo[i], O_RDWR);
    printf("%s\n",myfifo[i]);
}
while(1)
{
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            FD_ZERO(&set);
            FD_SET(fd[i], &set);
            n = select(fd[i]+1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            if (n > 0)
            {   
                r = read(fd[i], &demon1, sizeof(demon1));
                if(r !=-1)
                {
                    /*READ DATA*/
                }
            }
        }      
}
```

second program (there is n number of this program)

```
void signal_handler(int signum)
{
if (signum == SIGUSR1)
{
    /*STAFF*/
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDWR);
    write(fd, &demon1 , sizeof(demon1));
    close(fd);
}
}
```

every program has fifo named myfifo1 ,myfifo2.. and so on. 
Please help.

EDIT: Now i have this:

```
int max_fd;
while(1)
{
FD_ZERO(&set);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    FD_SET(fd[i], &set);
    if (fd[i]>max_fd) max_fd = fd[i];
}
n = select(max_fd+1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (n != 0)
{   
    int d;
    for (d = 0; d<FD_SETSIZE; d++) 
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(d,&set))
        {
            r = read(d, &demon1, sizeof(demon1));
            if(r !=-1)
            {
               /*CODE*/
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Reads only correct on first try, later on it reads only the first filedescriptor

apparently there is a diffrence between

```
 //n = select(max_fd+1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
 //if (n != -1)
```

and

```
    if (select(max_fd+1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL) != -1)
```

EDIT: It seems to work only on ubuntu virutal machine.. linux mint laptop does not.

Comment: You are using `select` incorrectly. It should not be called for each fd. The main point of `select` is that it can monitor multiple fds in a single call. You should fill `set` with all the fds and make a single `select` call for all of them.

Comment: You should not normally open fifos this way, you should open for reading or for writing, not reading and writing on the same descriptor.

Comment: with blocking mode? I dont think that is the reason?

Comment: You must reset the non-blocking mode on the file descriptor after each read.

Comment: Opening a fifo for O_RDWR makes no sense. It is either read or write. BTW: what is `demon1` ? BTW: select() returning -1 is **not an error**. Check errno, it could be EAGAIN, or a timer.

Comment: how to reset non-blocking mode on file descriptor?

Comment: It still seems to have the same problem.. Whats funny it seems to work on ubuntu virtual machine but on linux mint laptop no. Communication is blocked and nothing pops out (on ocassions sometimes one fifo is working and its always a diffrent one)..

Answer (score 1):

No you should build a reading set and then make a select call:

```
// Create the set of descriptor to select on
FD_ZERO(&set);
max_fd = 0;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    FD_SET(fd[i], &set);              // add the descriptor to the set
    if (fd[i]>max_fd) max_fd = fd[i]; // register the highest descriptor
}

// Then select on the set of descriptors
if (select(max_fd+1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL)!=-1) {
    // extract which descriptors are available for reading
    for (int d=0; d<FD_SETSIZE; d++) {
        if (FD_ISSET(d,&set)) {
            // something to read in descriptor d
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be if (select(max_fd+1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL)!=-1), anyway it doesn't work. Now it reads only from last descriptor

Comment: Something's wrong somewhere else. Observe the value of set before and after select. If something is incoherent find the problem accordingly. If values are coherent something may goes wrong on the sending part...

Comment: The set value is 0 before the select, is that right?

Comment: I actually can't belive it but I think it works! Thanks man! check edit